# Extremum, directional derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization

If a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ has all the directional derivatives zero at a point $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, does it imply that $f$ has an extremum at $c \in \mathbb{R}$? If so, how do I prove it?

Comment: It could be a saddle point.  $z = xy$ is  a simple counter example with a saddle point at (0,0)

Answer (score -1):

No, it doesn't because it is only a necessary condition for a local extremum. You should check your point $c$ for the fulfillment of a sufficient condition for a local extremum.